# Using list head as int in ML

Tags: list, ml

I need to make a function, in ML, where the arguments are a list and an int, and the function takes every element in the list and power it by the specified int. So I've already coded the following:

```
(* power function (power x y => x^y) *)
fun power x 0 = 1
| power x 1 = x
| power x y = x * (power x (y - 1));
```

and this is the main function:

```
fun powlist [] n = []
| powlist lst n = ((power hd(lst) n) :: (powlist tl(lst) n));
```

It makes sense, I think, but the compiler (moscow ML) shows the following:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBLdP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function application has the strongest binding power, also `hd(lst)` really is `hd lst`, hence `(power hd(lst) n)` is understood by the compiler as `(power hd lst n)`, which means the function `hd` is being passed as an argument to the `power` function instead of the list `lst`.

One way to amend this is to rearrange some parentheses:

```
fun powlist []  n = []
  | powlist lst n = (power (hd lst) n) :: (powlist (tl lst) n)
```

But it's not idiomatic SML code. A slightly better approach would be to use pattern-matching:

```
fun powlist []      n = []
  | powlist (h::tl) n = (power h n) :: (powlist tl n)
```

And probably the best approach would be to use the standard `List.map` function, which is more general and is implemented as [tail-recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) in some SML implementations:

```
fun powlist lst n = List.map (fn x => power x n) lst
```

Incidentally, the `power` function can be written a bit more concise:

```
fun power x 0 = 1
  | power x y = x * (power x (y - 1))
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much!